# Starting up MongoDB through Node.js and then connecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'd like to start the MongoDB through Node.js to save myself the trouble of having to do it manually each time, however I'm uncertain what the best method to use is, or for that matter, how to incorporate it, and therefore the dilemma.

I believe the reason that this code is not working (ECONNREFUSED) is that the mongod.exe is not given enough time to start up. If true, what would be the best method to around this? Some sort of loop? Checking the status of the DB somehow? Some sort of synchronous timer?

Ideally, the server should check first if the MongoDB is already running before attempting to start it up, and if it fails to start up and connect after so many attempts to do something else. This sounds like a good plan to me but unforunately I do not know where to start.

I'm really new to coding, and I'm perhaps a little too ambitious with my goals... if I'm doing anything wrong, please kindly let me know.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

var db

execFile("C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin/mongod.exe", ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);

});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', (err, database) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  db = database
  app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait till `mongodb` will start, then connect.
Here is the example

```
  execFile("C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.2/bin/mongod.exe",  ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db', (err, database) => {

   if (err) return console.log(err)
   db = database
   app.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log('listening on 3000')
    })
  })

 });
```

Also in your example you start mongod with --version parameter, and presumably your intention is to start the db itself, correct? So just drop `--version` parameter.

Comment: Oh wow! Just dropping the `--version` parameter made it work! I had thought that the parameter just displayed some additional information to the console and nothing more.

Comment: Do you know if it's worth checking first to see if MongoDB is already running?

Comment: Yes, sure, you could. Code above just makes sure that you first run the db, then connect.